# Magento2 - Admin takes too much time to save data

Tags: magento2, admin

I am facing a strange issue, whenever I try to save my category data, or update my category or create a new category it takes too much time in admin. Admin keeps on refreshing for a long period of time.

Why I call it strange, because it happens only on my stage site & not in my local env.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance.

Even when I click on any particular category to load that particalar category data it takes time.

Comment: Check your MySQL server configuration at the stage. Compare with your local

Comment: @Arjun Check your indexer mode and set it to *Update by Schedule* instead of *Update on Save*.

Comment: @Technocracker I have already tried that but not workign

Comment: @AmitBera Can php_memory_limit pay a role in this issue.